# insert using where clause in SQL table dynamically

Tags: sql, insert, where-clause

I am having a table `COMPONENTS` of 3 columns (`Sno`,`Component`,`Quantity`) among which I am writing `Sno` and `Component` columns initially and I want to fill the column 'quantity' using some expression(ex: `((d1+d2)*d3)` ) involving variables from another table **`SHEET(d1 int,d2 int ,d3 int,d4 int ,d5 int,d6 int)`**.

Here I need to write values to quantity column based on value in Sno column from COMPONENTS table(components.sno).

I used to keep expression value in 'x' and trying to insert into COMPONENTS as shown below:

```
insert into components(Quantity) values(x) 
where components.sno='y'; [Y is inetger starting from 0 to 70]
```

But the above query showing error at `where`

Please suggest me best SQL query to achieve this!
Thanks in Advance..!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do `INSERT` with `WHERE` clause unless it's `WHERE NOT EXISTS`, so just do:

```
INSERT INTO components(Quantity) VALUES(x)
```

Maybe you needed to do `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE components SET Quantity=x WHERE components.sno='y';
```

Comment: Did it help with your problem?

Comment: @RavitejA, if an answer solve your problem, please upvote it.

Answer (score -1):

Use an `IF` statement before the `insert` and don't use the `where` clause:

```
If <your condition>
  Begin <your statement>
End
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. To increase the chance of your response being accepted, and useful to future readers, I would suggest posting the entire text of the correct query, with code markdown (http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).