# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException on multiple WHERE query

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I am using my **quo_custname** that is bind in my **dropdownlist** and use its value to
Insert my data.So whenever I choose a value on my **dropdownlist quo_name** change
but whenever I use my class for mysql Insertion.

I get this error 
`Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.`

Here is my code:

```
 private void AddToQuotation()
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO JobQuotations
                            (quo_disount,quo_unitPrice,quo_TotalAmount,quo_finishing)
                             VALUES
                            ('@discount','@unitPrice','@totalAmount'
                            ,'@finishing')
                            WHERE quo_custname = '@customername'
                            AND quo_verified = 'no'",con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customername",DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Value.ToString());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@discount",txtDisc.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unitPrice",txtUnitPrice.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalAmount",lblTotalAmount.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        string script = "alert(\"Functioning!\");";

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
            "ServerControlScript", script, true);
    }
```

*Bonus question also how could I using **try and catch** so that it wouldn't break my program and get the SqlException name and the *Additional information*
in my **script** to popup a message.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17463904/inserting-using-where-clause-in-sql-table-dynamically

Comment: write your parameters `@customername` instead of `'@customername'` otherwise they will be recognized as string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement doesn't make much sense to me. You are mixing `insert into select` syntax with `insert into values` syntax. Also, you are using quotes around your parameters, which won't work (they are interpreted as literals now).

Are you sure you didn't mean to update?

```sql
update JobQuotations
set    quo_disount     = @discount
,      quo_unitPrice   = @unitPrice
,      quo_TotalAmount = @totalAmount
,      quo_finishing   = @finishing
where  quo_custname    = @customername
and    quo_verified    = 'no'
```

Comment: No I'm not updating.

Comment: So what is the purpose of the `where` then?

Comment: I am trying to insert this sqldata in my null columns.Their initial value was Null.Example : totalAmount is null so I need to insert value on it in order to have its price after I calculated it.

Comment: So that is an update right? The columns were null, so there is a row.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are making an insert statement while also specifying a WHERE condition. SQL inserts typically do not use WHERE conditions so you probably want to remove that part.

Answer (score 0):

for this  use update query that you have record in database.

Comment: There was already a comprehensive answer that goes into detail. No need for this comment.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `WHERE` clause in an `INSERT` statement, it will not work because we can't use a `where` clause with an `INSERT` statement. Either you have to use :

```
INSERT INTO JobQuotations(quo_disount,quo_unitPrice,quo_TotalAmount,quo_finishing)
                  VALUES('@discount','@unitPrice','@totalAmount','@finishing')
```

**or**

`UPDATE` statement (if you want to use `WHERE`).